# How in Qt creator (cmake) change "unused parameter" error to warning?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, cmake, warnings, gcc-warning

Is it possible to change an error in Qt creator (I assume this can be done in `CMakeLists.txt` file ) :

> /home/USER/programming/cpp_yahtzee/game.cpp:11: error: unused parameter ‘newPlayersName’ [-Werror=unused-parameter]

into a warning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually this was a problem of gcc flag `-Werror` in my `CMakeLists.txt` which converts all warnings into error.